# GREL multivalued JSON

Tags: json, foreach, openrefine, grel

I have a column with following contents in Open Refine

```
1. {"result":"Mango"}
2. {"result":"Banana"},{"result":"Apple"}
```

and I need resulting column

```
1. Mango
2. Banana | Apple
```

The expression I tried was

```
"forEach(value.parseJson().result).join(' | ')"
```

but this does not produce results.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example isn't valid JSON, so I'm not sure what the parse will produce -- probably just the first object. One approach would be to wrap each cell with square brackets (`[]`) to turn it into a JSON array. This will give you something that `forEach` can operate on.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tom Morris

Modified cells as

```
1. [{"result":"Mango"}]
2. [{"result":"Banana"},{"result":"Apple"}]
```

Then solution used was

```
forEach(value.parseJson(),v,v.result).join(' | ')
```